# Forcing evaluation of CSS rules (Workaround)

Tags: css

Given the problem that browsers (Internet Explorer in my case) sometimes don't correctly apply complex CSS rules, how could one possibly force the evaluation?

A sampe rule:

```
body[data-some-flag="3"] #someElement .someClass svg stop:first-child {
  stop-color: #012d71;
}
```

The data flag will be set from JS and the styling should change accordingly. In some real world application this will *sometimes* not work, but when opening F11 browser tools and just selecting the node in the DOM explorer, the rule will then be applied.

Is there a common workaround for this kind of browser issues?

Something like

```
node.recalculateCssRules()
```

Comment: Please, provide more information(HTML, css, Jquery, jsfiddle and etc).

Comment: Which IE version? Maybe is about complex selector support and it won't load even if you reapply your CSS. In that case you will need to apply less complex CSS selectors, use IE-specific selectors or even use JS to manually load some CSS properties

Comment: The CSS rules are often applied correctly in IE9-11, just sometimes not. Of cause I could do rework the entire HTML and CSS so that the bug won't occur, but I would be interested if someone knows a common workaround

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me is removing the node and inserting it again at the same position.

This seems to force the browser to evaluate all CSS rules again relevant for the node.

Answer (score 0):

If you think the browser is not giving priotiry to your css and some other css is overriding it, then you can put `!important` beside the property to force the browser to use that property.

For Example:

```
body[data-some-flag="3"] #someElement .someClass svg stop:first-child {
  stop-color: #012d71 !important;
}
```

Comment: I didn't mean this. This would be useful if MY css had a bug, but not if the CSS selector engine of the browser has a bug